# .Net Core minify css not working for divide(/) or front slash

Tags: css, asp.net-core, .net-core

The below css minification is not working. But without the "/" rule the css file is minified perfectly. Do not know why as the rule is valid.

```
.main_menu nav ul li ul.mega_menu {
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px rgb(0 0 0 / 10); // This line causing issue
    border-radius: 0px;
    left: 100px;
    right: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    z-index: 9;
    top: 140%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: .Net Core minify CSS means? Which package / CLI tool you're using for the minification?

Comment: Are you saying that using the box-shadow attribute in your css prevents you from shrinking your css file?

Comment: It is the nuget package named BundlerMinifier.Core.

Answer (score 1):

You have to upgrade NUglify package to > 1.17.7
As of answering this the latest I've tested is 1.20.2

The latest BundlerMinifier.Core and latest WebOptimizer.Core for minification both reference an older version of NUglify (1.5.14).

> 1.17.6 - Fixes use of spaces instead of commas in CSS RGB values